# In Ruby, how do variables get passed into arguments without a method call?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, parameters, arguments

Given the following code:

```
def method
  words = "33"
  return words
end

def callmethod
  words = method
  result =  printout(words)
end

def printout(words)
  puts (words)
end

callmethod #will print out --> "33" (words from method)
```

How does Ruby recognize that the variable `words` is part of the method call (`callmethod`) when it has not been called explicitly? In this case, the line I am specifically talking about result = `printout(words)`. It seems that this function is picking up the variable words (return value of method), even though I haven't used the method call to explicitly put it in. Can someone explain to me how this is possible?

Comment: `words = method` is the same as `words = method()`. You are calling the method named `method`, so `words` will now contain the value `33`.

Comment: What did you think the line `words = method` was doing, if not invoking `method` and storing the returned value in a new local variable called `words`?

Comment: I get the fact that it returned a value and stored in under words. Didn't really get the fact that how the function grabbed the local variable words without having to be passed through a method.

Comment: `words` is available in all three methods because you either declare and define it locally, or pass it in as an argument. Every use of `words` is working because you've explicitly made it available for use, no method is "grabbing" another method's local variable. I'm still not sure where your confusion is. `words` is explicitly defined in `method`, it's explicitly defined in `callmethod`, and it's explicitly passed into `printout`. None of these variables are the same variable, they just happen to have the same name and value. Each is local to the method where it is used.

Comment: FYI Your code could be rewritten identically but with unique variable names, which might clear up some of your confusion: https://gist.github.com/meagar/9b721ea5356aee05d9dd1916d03c2e83

Comment: I guess my confusion is from thinking setting parameters are separate from variables. I thought they do not take variables from outside the method (local variable in this case), but only serve to pass arguments from method calls that are explicit i.e.: method(3).

Comment: @programmer321 Every time ruby sees the name of a variable, it will replace that name with the contents of the variable. It doesn't matter if the variable is in an expression or as an argument to a function. The only exception to this rule is when you assign a value to a variable. In that case the variable will get a new value. In (almost) all other cases Ruby replaces the name of the variable with its contents.

Comment: So if you have `a = 1; b = 2; c = 3`. And then write `z = a + b + c` it will be equivalent to `z = 1 + 2 + 3`. If you write `z = func(a, b, c)` it will be equivalent to `z = func(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Thank you @Casper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `callmethod` method `words` is a local variable with the value of return value of method `method`.

`printout(words)` works as expected, because you are passing it a value of local variable `words`, which is string `"33"`.

In Ruby `method_name()` are optional while calling a method. If you happen to have a local variable with the same name, as a method, to make Ruby know you want to call a method, not to get a value of local variable, you can say `method_name()`. But there is a better/recommended option - `self.method_name`.

Comment: Although you *can* add braces, in practice you almost never do: `self.x` is what most style guides recommend vs. `x()`.

Comment: can you give an example maybe using the previous example of how to rewrite it with self.x?

Comment: @programmer321 in this case it won't make much sense, because it is unnecessary, but the next is equivalent to what you had: `def callmethod
  words = self.method
  result =  self.printout(words)
end`